# Get XML node value when previous node value conditions are true (without looping)

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq-to-xml

Sample XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Root>
  <PhoneType dataType="string">
    <Value>CELL</Value>
  </PhoneType>
  <PhonePrimaryYn dataType="string">
    <Value>Y</Value>
  </PhonePrimaryYn>
  <PhoneNumber dataType="string">
    <Value>555-555-5554</Value>
  </PhoneNumber>
  <PhonePrimaryYn dataType="string">
    <Value>Y</Value>
  </PhonePrimaryYn>
  <PhoneType dataType="string">
    <Value>HOME</Value>
  </PhoneType>
  <PhoneNumber dataType="string">
    <Value>555-555-5555</Value>
  </PhoneNumber>    
</Root>
```

Without looping through each nodelist, can someone tell me (either with LINQ-to-XML or by other means) how I can perform the following?

In the XML sample you see two groups of 'PhoneType', 'PhonePrimaryYn', and 'PhoneNumber' type code groups.  The first group of three relate to each other.  The second group of three relate to each other as well, and so on.

Lets say I want to know what the cell phone number is.

I get that cell phone number when the 'PhoneType' 'Value' is 'CELL', the 'PhonePrimaryYn' 'Value' is 'Y', I get that 'PhoneNumber' 'Value' of '555-555-5554'.  You get the idea hopefully.

I'd like to know if it is possible to get that 'PhoneNumber' value (cell phone for example) without having to loop through each nodelist group of the particular type.

Do anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm trying to make a UI for users to use which translates their settings (drop-down values) into code I can plug in values to.  I can get the values I need using SelectNodes("Email | FaxNumber | PhoneNumber | Pager | Webpage"), SelectNodes("PhoneType"), and SelectNodes("PhonePrimaryYn").  I'm looping through each Email/PhoneNumber XMLNode to get what I need (hence the "without looping" verbiage) using 100 lines of code, but I wanted to know if there was a quicker way where the user chosen values could just be plugged into an expression build piece of code, without hard coding everything.

Comment: I said "show us", not "tell us". And I meant for you to edit your question to "show us".

Comment: Not allowed to show proprietary business code.  I really appreciate your input Ryan Thomas and Shar1er80.  Thank you for your time today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE

Using an XDocument vs an XmlDocument, I believe this does what you're asking without using loops.

This is dependent on the elements being in the order of

`<PhoneType> <PhonePrimaryYN> <PhoneNumber>`

```
string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
    "<Root>" + 
    "  <PhoneType dataType=\"string\">" + 
    "    <Value>CELL</Value>" + 
    "  </PhoneType>" + 
    "  <PhonePrimaryYn dataType=\"string\">" + 
    "    <Value>Y</Value>" + 
    "  </PhonePrimaryYn>" + 
    "  <PhoneNumber dataType=\"string\">" + 
    "    <Value>555-555-5554</Value>" + 
    "  </PhoneNumber>" + 
    "  <PhonePrimaryYn dataType=\"string\">" + 
    "    <Value>Y</Value>" + 
    "  </PhonePrimaryYn>" + 
    "  <PhoneType dataType=\"string\">" + 
    "    <Value>HOME</Value>" + 
    "  </PhoneType>" + 
    "  <PhoneNumber dataType=\"string\">" + 
    "    <Value>555-555-5555</Value>" + 
    "  </PhoneNumber>    " +
    "  <PhoneType dataType=\"string\">" +
    "    <Value>CELL</Value>" +
    "  </PhoneType>" +
    "  <PhonePrimaryYn dataType=\"string\">" +
    "    <Value>Y</Value>" +
    "  </PhonePrimaryYn>" +
    "  <PhoneNumber dataType=\"string\">" +
    "    <Value>555-555-9999</Value>" +
    "  </PhoneNumber>" + 
    "</Root>";

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
if (xDoc.Root != null)
{
    var tmp = (from item in xDoc.Root.Descendants()
                where item.Name == "PhoneType" && item.Value == "CELL"
                select new
                            {
                                PhoneNumber = item.NextNode.NextNode
                            }).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(((XElement)tmp[i].PhoneNumber).Value);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
555-555-5554
555-555-9999
```

### OLD ANSWER

When I loaded your sample XML into an `XmlDocument` I saw that it's `InnerText` property contained the following:

```
CELLY555-555-5554YHOME555-555-5555
```

From here, I thought Regex would be a good method for extracting CELL numbers using the pattern:

```
"CELL[NY](\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4})"
```

The pattern looks for the word "CELL", followed by a 'N' or 'Y', then the phone number in the format `###-###-#####`.  The phone number is in a capture group and if a match is found it can be accessed like this following example illustrates.

I added another CELL entry to show that you can get all CELL numbers in your XML.  So the `InnerText` property, of the `XmlDocument`, now looks like

`CELLY555-555-5554YHOME555-555-5555CELLY555-555-9999`

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" +
    "<Root>" + 
    "  <PhoneType dataType=\"string\">" + 
    "    <Value>CELL</Value>" + 
    "  </PhoneType>" + 
    "  <PhonePrimaryYn dataType=\"string\">" + 
    "    <Value>Y</Value>" + 
    "  </PhonePrimaryYn>" + 
    "  <PhoneNumber dataType=\"string\">" + 
    "    <Value>555-555-5554</Value>" + 
    "  </PhoneNumber>" + 
    "  <PhonePrimaryYn dataType=\"string\">" + 
    "    <Value>Y</Value>" + 
    "  </PhonePrimaryYn>" + 
    "  <PhoneType dataType=\"string\">" + 
    "    <Value>HOME</Value>" + 
    "  </PhoneType>" + 
    "  <PhoneNumber dataType=\"string\">" + 
    "    <Value>555-555-5555</Value>" + 
    "  </PhoneNumber>    " +
    "  <PhoneType dataType=\"string\">" +
    "    <Value>CELL</Value>" +
    "  </PhoneType>" +
    "  <PhonePrimaryYn dataType=\"string\">" +
    "    <Value>Y</Value>" +
    "  </PhonePrimaryYn>" +
    "  <PhoneNumber dataType=\"string\">" +
    "    <Value>555-555-9999</Value>" +
    "  </PhoneNumber>" + 
    "</Root>");

Match match = Regex.Match(xmlDocument.InnerText, "CELL[NY](\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4})");
while (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
    match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Results:

```
555-555-5554
555-555-9999
```

Comment: I can see where this would work if the numbers were always formatted the same, but it doesn't account for international numbers and their different formats.

Comment: If I add in another grouping, how would I go about handling it?:    <PhoneType dataType="string">
    <Value>EMAIL</Value>
  </PhoneType>
  <PhonePrimaryYn dataType="string">
    <Value>Y</Value>
  </PhonePrimaryYn>
  <Email dataType="string">
    <Value>JerryB@JerryB.com</Value>
  </Email>

Comment: I can't predict the different types/formats used.  That is the issue.  That's why taking the value between the 'Value' tags (whatever it is) might be best.  Then I can use regex to only keep the numbers after obtaining the value.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would change how the XML works so you have all the information for one phone number in one block like this

```
<phoneStructure>
   <type>CELL</type>
   <value>0123</value>
   <primary>false</primary>
</phoneStructure>
```

Then you can use this XPath to select the entire phone structure where it is a cell phone or change it to primary and then read the value from there.

```
//PhoneStructure[Type='Cell']
```

If you need any more help with this let me know.

Comment: I totally agree on the structure change.  However, I'm working with another company's XML and their structure so I don't have that luxury.